# How to make CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton able to works in vertical mode?

Tags: visual-c++, mfc, mfc-feature-pack

The MFC Feature Pack toolbar combo-button (class `CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton`) works perfectly in  horizontal toolbar mode. But in vertical layout mode it is the simple press button without combobox feature.

How to make [`CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb982770.aspx) able to works in vertical mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This my solution. I overwrote the behavior of the buttons in vertical mode. And now the button shows combobox drop down window when it is pressed in vertical mode.

You should use class CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton instead of CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton in [`ReplaceButton()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb983613%28v=vs.140%29.aspx) method when you add combobox button to your toolbar.

*Example*: In the images below you can see the behavior of the buttons in the horizontal and vertical modes.

**Horizontal mode**

[image: Horizontal mode]

**Vertical mode**

[image: Vertical left mode] 
[image: Vertical right mode]

**Class code:**

```
class CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton
    : public CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton
{
    DECLARE_SERIAL(CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton)

public:
    typedef CMFCToolBarComboBoxButton TBase;

protected:

    bool                m_bDoVerticalMode;

public:
    CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton(bool bDoVerticalMode = true);
    CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton(UINT uiID, int iImage, DWORD dwStyle = CBS_DROPDOWNLIST, int iWidth = 0, bool bDoVerticalMode = true);

    virtual ~CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton();

    virtual void Serialize(CArchive& ar);

    virtual BOOL OnClick(CWnd* pWnd, BOOL bDelay = TRUE);
    virtual void OnChangeParentWnd(CWnd* pWndParent);
    virtual void OnMove();
    virtual void OnSize(int iSize);

protected:
    void AdjustVerticalRect();
};


/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton
IMPLEMENT_SERIAL(CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton, CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton::TBase, VERSIONABLE_SCHEMA | 1)

    CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton::CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton(bool bDoVerticalMode /*= true*/)
    : m_bDoVerticalMode(bDoVerticalMode)
{}

CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton::CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton(UINT uiID, int iImage, DWORD dwStyle /*= CBS_DROPDOWNLIST*/, int iWidth /*= 0*/, bool bDoVerticalMode /*= true*/)
    : TBase(uiID, iImage, dwStyle, iWidth)
    , m_bDoVerticalMode(bDoVerticalMode)
{}

CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton::~CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton()
{}

void CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton::Serialize(CArchive& ar)
{
    TBase::Serialize(ar);

    if (ar.IsLoading()) {
        ar >> m_bDoVerticalMode;
    }
    else {
        ar << m_bDoVerticalMode;
    }
}

BOOL CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton::OnClick(CWnd* pWnd, BOOL bDelay /*= TRUE*/)
{
    BOOL bRes = FALSE;

    bool bDefault = m_bHorz || !m_bDoVerticalMode;
    if (!bDefault) {
        if (IsFlatMode()) {

            if (m_pWndEdit == NULL) {
                m_pWndCombo->SetFocus();
            }
            else {
                m_pWndEdit->SetFocus();
            }

            m_pWndCombo->ShowDropDown();

            if (pWnd != NULL) {
                pWnd->InvalidateRect(m_rectCombo);
            }

            bRes = TRUE;
        }
    }

    if (bDefault) {
        bRes = TBase::OnClick(pWnd, bDelay);
    }

    return bRes;
}

void CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton::OnChangeParentWnd(CWnd* pWndParent)
{
    TBase::OnChangeParentWnd(pWndParent);

    if (!m_bHorz & m_bDoVerticalMode) {
        AdjustVerticalRect();
    }
}

void CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton::OnMove()
{
    TBase::OnMove();

    if (!m_bHorz & m_bDoVerticalMode) {
        AdjustVerticalRect();
    }
}

void CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton::OnSize(int iSize)
{
    TBase::OnSize(iSize);

    if (!m_bHorz & m_bDoVerticalMode) {
        AdjustVerticalRect();
    }
}

void CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton::AdjustVerticalRect()
{
    ASSERT(m_bDoVerticalMode);
    ASSERT(!m_bHorz);

    if (m_pWndCombo->GetSafeHwnd() == NULL || m_rect.IsRectEmpty()) {

        m_rectCombo.SetRectEmpty();
        m_rectButton.SetRectEmpty();
        return;
    }

    CMFCToolBar* pParentBar = nullptr;
    {
        CWnd* pNextBar = m_pWndCombo->GetParent();
        while (pParentBar == nullptr && pNextBar != nullptr) {
            pParentBar = DYNAMIC_DOWNCAST(CMFCToolBar, pNextBar);
            pNextBar = pNextBar->GetParent();
        }
    }

    if (IsCenterVert() && (!m_bTextBelow || m_strText.IsEmpty()) && (pParentBar != nullptr))
    {
        const int nRowHeight = pParentBar->GetRowHeight();
        const int yOffset = std::max<>(0, (nRowHeight - m_rect.Height()) / 2);

        m_rect.OffsetRect(0, yOffset);
    }

{
    CRect rect;
    m_pWndCombo->GetWindowRect(&rect);
    const int nWidth = std::max<>(rect.Width(), m_iWidth);

    rect.left = m_rect.left;
    rect.top = m_rect.top;
    rect.right = m_rect.left + nWidth;
    rect.bottom = m_rect.top + m_nDropDownHeight;

    if ((pParentBar != nullptr) && pParentBar->IsDocked()) {
        const UINT nID = pParentBar->GetParentDockSite()->GetDockSiteID();
        if (nID == AFX_IDW_DOCKBAR_RIGHT) {
            rect.left = m_rect.right - nWidth;
            rect.right = m_rect.right;
        }
    }

    m_pWndCombo->SetWindowPos(NULL, rect.left, rect.top, rect.Width(), rect.Height(), SWP_NOZORDER | SWP_NOACTIVATE);
    m_pWndCombo->SetEditSel(-1, 0);
}

{
    m_pWndCombo->GetWindowRect(&m_rectCombo);
    m_pWndCombo->ScreenToClient(&m_rectCombo);
    m_pWndCombo->MapWindowPoints(m_pWndCombo->GetParent(), &m_rectCombo);

}

if (m_bFlat) {
    m_rectButton = m_rectCombo;
}
else {
    m_rectButton.SetRectEmpty();
}
}

// CVerticalableToolBarComboBoxButton
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```